# get previous data of socket(connected user) after refresh or disconnect using socket.io and node.js

Tags: node.js, sockets

Hi i am mew to socket and node.js and developing a game application in which two users (separate browsers) plays game.
i have used server.js for node/socket and cilent.js from where user events are handled.
suppose both users are connected and playing game , if one user get disconnected or refresh browser then i am not getting its previous data like username etc. I tried to get socket id which is disconnected in

```
socket.on('disconnect', function()
    {///timer used here in which i can get socket id of disconnected but what next
});
```

but next what to do, how would i know that after refersh/disconnect
    same user get connected and how to get its previous data like username?

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep track of disconnected users you have to create an array which will contain usernames of users which are disconnected from room, To implement this try below code,

```
socket.on('disconnect', function()
    array.push(socket.username);
});
```

In order to get username of client to push in array, You will have to add username when user connects to room which can be achieved by as show below,

```
socket.on('joinroom',function(data){
    socket.username = "user1";
}
```

Now you have an array which has list of usernames who were disconnected, Now when user connects to room put for loop which will rotate through array and if username is found in array then you got to know that same user is connected then you can add that user to previous room.

To get previous room of user from which user was disconnected you will have to add room also in array can be done by,

```
var obj={username:socket.username , room:socket.room}
array.push(obj);
```

And when user connects to room you will have to add room also,

```
socket.on('joinroom',function(data){
    socket.username = "user1";
    socket.room = "roomname";
}
```

Hope this will help